# Torsion Tensor, always zero?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-derivative, tensor-products, differential-forms, tensors

So, I'm having a bit of trouble finding what I've done wrong. If we define the torsion tensor:

$$ T(u, v) = \nabla_u v - \nabla_v u - [u, v] $$

Then I substitute:

$$ T(u, v) = \nabla_u v - \nabla_v u - u(v) + v(u) $$

And then I can write (I'm not bothering to write the $\otimes$ everwhere:

$$ T(u, v) = {\partial v \over \partial x^k} dx^k(u)  - {\partial u \over \partial x^k} dx^k(v) - u^ke_k(v) + v^ke_k(u) $$

And then I write:

$$ T(u, v) = {\partial v \over \partial x^k} u^k  - {\partial u \over \partial x^k} v^k - u^k{\partial v \over \partial x^k } + v^k{\partial u \over \partial x^k } $$

At this point, it seems that everything just crosses out to give me a torsion tensor of zero. So somewhere along the way, I must have assumed that the te torsion tensor was zero. But I'm not exactly sure where.

I was thinking that perhaps $u(v) = u^k {\partial v \over \partial x^k}$ only makes sense in a torsion free space, but I'm not quite sure why that would be the case. So could anybody point out what I did wrong here.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: $\nabla_{u} v$ is the covariant derivative, which does not express simply as $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x^k} u^{k} $ in a chart

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by that, couldn't you then write $v = v^i e_i$, then use the product rule, and get the standard expression for the covariant derivative, involving the Christoffel symbols from there?

Comment: When you write $\nabla_u v= (u^i\partial_i v^j)e_j$, you implicitly assume that the Christoffel symbols are identically zero. In coordinates, torsion shows up as the antisymmetric part of the Christoffel symbols $\Gamma^i{}_{jk}-\Gamma^i{}_{kj}$. In general, you get $$\nabla_u v=(u^i\partial_i v^j)e_j+u^iv^j\nabla_{e_i}e_j=(u^i\partial_i v^j)e_j+u^iv^j\Gamma^k{}_{ij}e_k$$

Comment: I’ve done $$\nabla_u v = {\partial(v^i e_i) \over \partial x^k} u^k = \left({\partial(v^i ) \over \partial x^k} e_i + v^i {\partial e_i \over \partial x^k } \right) u^k$$ Which does expand to the same result that you got. But the problem is, that my u(v) seems to also get a christoffel symbol, and that must be where I’m wrong.